# xpath select 2 attributes when 1 attibute exist and the other is not present

Tags: xpath, attributes

I have this XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="Myxslt.xml" type="application/xml"?>
<Player>
<information id="2" >Gretzky</information>
</Player>
<Player>
<information id="3" goalie="true">Fuhr</information>
</Player>
```

I want to retrieve only player that have an information's id and **NOT the goalie**.
This is my "test" that doesn't work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="//*[@id|not(@goalie)]">
....
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**this line is not working :**

```
<xsl:template match="//*[@id|not(@goalie)]">
```

It's like I'm having an error inside.

It works correctly with 1 attribute :

```
<xsl:template match="//*[@id">
```

or

```
<xsl:template match="//*[@goalie">
```

Can someone have an idea on this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want elements the have an id *and* don't have the goalie attribute then use two predicates:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@id][not(@goalie)]">
```

With multiple predicates each one filters the list resulting from the previous one, so they are effectively "anded" together.

Note also that you don't need the leading `//` in match patterns as patterns are matched at all levels by default unless they are absolute paths starting with a single `/`.